# Pascal: Get field from LPSYSTEMTIME record

Tags: winapi, record, pascal

I'm using the Win32 api to get date and time of a file. I have a LPSYSTEMTIME structure, and I'm trying to print its wYear variable.

I've got a function (GetFileDate):

```
function GetFileDate : LPSYSTEMTIME
var
    CheckFile: Long;
    FileTime: LPFILETIME;
    FileTimeReturn: LPFILETIME;
    SystemTimeReturn: LPSYSTEMTIME;
begin
    CheckFile := CreateFile(PChar('main.pas'), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NIL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    GetFileTime(CheckFile, FileTime, NIL, NIL);
    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTime, FileTimeReturn);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(FileTimeReturn, SystemTimeReturn);
    GetFileDate := SystemTimeReturn;
end;
```

But when I do this...

```
begin
    Write(GetFileDate.wYear);
end.
```

It spits back

> ```
> main.pas(22,20) Error: Illegal qualifier
> main.pas(22,20) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "identifier WYEAR" found
> Fatal: Compilation aborted
> ```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPSYSTEMTIME` is a pointer to a `SYSTEMTIME` structure.  Try using the `^` operator to dereference that pointer, eg:

```
Write(GetFileDate^.wYear);
```

Or:

```
Write(GetFileDate()^.wYear);
```

With that said, aside from the fact that you are not doing any error handling at all, your `GetFileDate()` implementation is passing the wrong parameter values to the various API functions.  That code should not even compile, let alone run correctly.

Try this instead:

```
function GetFileDate : SYSTEMTIME;
var 
  CheckFile: HANDLE; 
  FileTime: FILETIME; 
  FileTimeReturn: FILETIME; 
  SystemTimeReturn: SYSTEMTIME;
  GetFileDateResult: SYSTEMTIME;
begin 
  ZeroMemory(@GetFileDateResult, SizeOf(GetFileDateResult));
  CheckFile := CreateFile('FullPathTo\main.pas', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NIL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0); 
  if CheckFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    if GetFileTime(CheckFile, @FileTime, nil, nil) then
    begin
      if FileTimeToLocalFileTime(@FileTime, @FileTimeReturn) then
      begin
        if FileTimeToSystemTime(@FileTimeReturn, @SystemTimeReturn) then
          GetFileDateResult := SystemTimeReturn;
      end;
    end;
    CloseHandle(CheckFile);
  end; 
  GetFileDate := GetFileDateResult;
end; 

begin   
  Write(GetFileDate.wYear);   
end.
```

Alternatively, I would suggest using `FindFirstFile()` instead of `CreateFile()` so you do not have to open the file just to get its date.  The filesystem can supply that information, eg:

```
function GetFileDate : SYSTEMTIME;
var 
  CheckFile: HANDLE; 
  FindFileData: WIN32_FIND_DATA;
  FileTimeReturn: FILETIME; 
  SystemTimeReturn: SYSTEMTIME;
  GetFileDateResult: SYSTEMTIME;
begin 
  ZeroMemory(@GetFileDateResult, SizeOf(GetFileDateResult));
  CheckFile := FindFirstFile('FullPathTo\main.pas', @FindFileData);
  if CheckFile <> 0 then
  begin
    if FileTimeToLocalFileTime(@FindFileData.ftCreationTime, @FileTimeReturn) then
    begin
      if FileTimeToSystemTime(@FileTimeReturn, @SystemTimeReturn) then
        GetFileDateResult := SystemTimeReturn;
    end;
    FindClose(CheckFile);
  end; 
  GetFileDate := GetFileDateResult;
end;
```

Comment: I actually already tried that, but it just says there was Runtime error 216 at $75C58D46. Then some memory junk.

Comment: @SuperDisk: Then edit your question and post more code that shows `GetFileDate`.

Comment: Your `GetFileDate()` implementation is completely wrong. You are passing uninitialized pointers to the various API functions. Had the compiler accepted your code, it would have crashed at runtime.